# setting up a Makefile / Configure project from an existing makefile

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, qt, makefile

Just a little suggestion, I'm handling an huge project that has to build about 34 modules. The project is completely cross platform and developed mainly in Visual Studio 2010. Now in the past, consider the amount of stuff I had to do, I managed to create manually a Makefile that invokes g++ as well as the QT building processes on the linux/mac platform.

Considering this Makefile has became somewhat unmanageable manually, can you suggest me a walkthrough with some sort of integrated environment on linux/mac (eclipse???) to build a makefile visually and also a Configure-for-dummies to make it fully opensource with the configure script ?

Thanks !

Comment: Qt's `qmake` and `.pro` files maybe? Plus a text editor.

Comment: the project isn't QT-only, it has only a lot of modules from plain c++

Comment: I think that will not prevent you from using qmake - the tool that generates makefiles based on .pro file. You can use non Qt libs with it too.

Comment: There is also Cmake.